# Solving the system $\cos x-\cos(x+y+z)=0$, $\cos y-\cos(x+y+z)=0$, $\cos z-\cos(x+y+z)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\cos(x) - \cos(x + y + z) & = & 0 \\[2mm]
\cos(y) - \cos(x + y + z) & = & 0 \\[2mm]
\cos(z) - \cos(x + y + z) & = & 0
\end{array}\right.$$
I understand that this is really a system, the answer is should be $$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
but I get that $y = -z$.
And I can't find any problem here.

Comment: How did you get $y=-z$? If $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=-1$, this is not a solution to the system. The point you have $(\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi/2)$ does work though! There will be a LOT more solutions than just this. $y=-z$ does not describe them though.

Comment: $$\cos x = \cos y \iff x = y + 2 k \pi \text{ or } x = - y + 2 k \pi$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if:
$$\cos(A)-\cos(B)=0\\
\cos(A)=\cos(B)$$
then:
$$B=\pm A+2k\pi\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
so you can convert your system into:
$$x+y+z=\pm x+2k_1\pi\\x+y+z=\pm y+2k_2\pi\\
x+y+z=\pm z+2k_3\pi$$
there will be many, many solutions to this. If we ignore the $\pm$ for now (taking one branch if you will) then we get:
$$(y+z)+(x+z)+(x+y)=2k\pi$$
or:
$$x+y+z=k\pi$$
taking all the possible combinations of $\pm$ and values of $k$ you will see how dense the solutions are